# Byte operations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, byte

I would like to get a **clue** on how I can get Ruby to work with byte arrays

The below code is C#:

```
int t = (GetTime() / 60) //t is time in seconds divided by 60s (1 min)
byte[] myArray = new byte[64];
myArray[0] = (byte)(t >> 24);
myArray[1] = (byte)(t >> 16);
```

Any idea how I can get this to work in Ruby?

Comment: What have you tried? On Stack Overflow, you're supposed to show us what you've written, explain why it didn't work, and we'll help you fix it. As is, it looks like you haven't tried anything and want someone to write it for you, which isn't a good way to go since Stack Overflow isn't a code conversion service.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to work with arrays of integers and use `Array#pack` to pack the result into a binary string. E.g.

```
[65, 66, 67].pack('C*')
```

Returns `ABC`

Another way would be to manipulate a string directly when the encoding is set to "ASCII-8BIT"

Answer (score 0):

Ruby can do bitwise operations and you can use a normal array, so I don't see a problem.
I don't use C# at the moment so I can't check if the results are the same.

```
t = Time.now.to_i / 60 #t is time in seconds divided by 60s (1 min)
myArray = []
myArray[0] = t >> 24
myArray[1] = t >> 16
p myArray #=>[1, 360]
```